# jquery live function not working for a specific selector

Tags: jquery

i'm having trouble applying .live function to a specific input tag having a unique id. Am i doing it the wrong way? Any suggestions?

```
$('input.newQty').live('change', function(){
}); //works

$('input.newQty[id="'+naam+'"]').live('change', function(){
}); //does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: If you must use live events in this case then I would fork out the function that is the event handler and not have it as an anonymous function. This is probably what I would do.

```
function myChangeHandler(e){
if($(this).attr("id")==naam))
{
    //found the right input, hook this event handler to the input directly and unbind it from all others
    $("input.newQty").die("change",myChangeHandler);
    $(this).bind("change",myChangeHandler);
}
//rest of the code goes here

}

$("input.newQty").live("change",myChangeHandler);
```

As far as I know live selectors can not be dynamic. As in you can not construct a selector for a live event by joining variables on run time. They need to be evaluated in entirety for them to work.

Hence you can not have a live expression as

```
$('input.newQty[id="'+naam+'"]').live('change', function(){
});
```

Your best approach will be to use it on the class selector as you have done correctly.

Comment: that sounds logical enuf..what do u suggest for the problem i'm stuck at?

Comment: I have given the updated code. Though it can be tweaked even further as it will keep on calling die() and bind() on the input with unique id. You might want to store a flag to say the routine has been attached via bind and not call bind() again

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
$('#'+ naam).live('change', function() {
    // ...
});
```

Or if you want to use a `name` attribute instead of `id` which must be unique:

```
$('input.newQty[name="' + naam + '"]').live('change', function() {
    // ...

});
```

Comment: @Darin how does it change anything? it's all about selecting the 'name' attr then

Comment: @Aakash Goel, are you trying to select by `id` or by `name`?

Comment: @Aakash Goel. id's are supposed to be unique. you are supposed to access it  as $('#id').live().

Comment: @abdul come on!! u r defying the purpose of the question!!